# Monogame 3.4 OpenGL Song: Specified stream is not a wave file

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, monogame

I'm using latest stable Monogame vesion (3.4.0.456)

When i use the MonoGame OpenGL template in Visual Studio i get an exception when try to load a song (previously converted using Content Pipeline):

```
private Song mySong;
mySong = Content.Load<Song>("Sound/Music");
```

The exception thrown on says: "Specified stream is not a wave file"

I converted the Music.mp3 via Content Pipeline and have the Music.xnb and Music.m4a on my bin\Content\Music folder

The SoundEffectects plays correctly even in Monogame OpenGL template

The same code but using the Monogame Windows DirectX template runs fine.

Obiously i don't want convert my Music.mp3 to wav an use SoundEffect instead Song, because the final wav is too huge.

Note 1: Also tried with ogg and wma songs formats with the same result

Note 2: I also installed all stuff (Mono, Monogame and Monodevelop) on an Ubuntu Virtual Machie and the same code compile without exceptions but the song is not played (SoundEffects runs fine in Ubuntu Virtual Machine)

Comment: It creates an m4a for me in the built content folder, but can't play it. Same project but in DX mode works, but doesn't have Fullscreen.